# How to dynamically select the property of flex to set value?

Tags: javascript

```
object.style.flex-direction="column";
```

I tried to achieve this in a JavaScript function, but I don't know if it's possible to replace the property name with variable name.

Can I use a variable name instead of a property name in the above expression, i.e.

```
object.style.applyFlexProp = "column";
```

where `applyFlexProp` will be assigned at runtime? It can be either, `flex-direction`, `justify-content`, `align-content`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `object.style.flex-direction="column";` with `object.style.flexDirection="column";`

When using JavaScript, replace a CSS `some-thing` with camelcase `someThing`.

This is because `-` is not a valid identifier character.

To apply the key dynamically, use the `[]` notation.
`object.style["flexDirection"] = "column"`;

Comment: Thanks dwmorrin................but instead of property name i want to use some variable name, this is not about "-" or camelCase.

problem is, expression is not recognizing variable here
object.style.flexDirection="column"; ==> object.style.applyFlexProp="column";

Comment: @gaaurav  sorry - I missed that part!  Yes, just use the `[]` notation.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Buddy......it worked, I tried it earlier, but god knows what was the issue than :)......cheers

Comment: I guess i was using the variable name with "quotes".......it has to be without quotes (if its variable name.
object.style[applyFlexDirection] = "column" ==>applyFlexDirection is a variable